# How to optimize this code on spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

How to make this code more efficient in Spark?
I need to calculate minimum, maximum, count, mean from data.
Here is my sample data,

> Name Shop Money
>   A Shop001 99.99
>   A Shop001 87.15
>   B Shop001 3.99
>   ...

Now I try to organize my data to generate mean, min, max, count by Name+Shop (key).
Then get the result by collect().
Here is my code in spark,

def tupleDivide(y):
    return float(y[0])/y[1]

def smin(a, b):
    return min(a, b)

def smax(a, b):
    return max(a, b)

raw = sgRDD.map(lambda x: getVar(parserLine(x),list_C+list_N)).cache()
cnt = raw.map(lambda (x,y,z): (x+"_"+y, 1)).countByKey()
sum = raw.map(lambda (x,y,z): (x+"_"+y, z)).reduceByKey(add)
min = raw.map(lambda (x,y,z): (x+"_"+y, z)).reduceByKey(smin)
max = raw.map(lambda (x,y,z): (x+"_"+y, z)).reduceByKey(smax)
raw_cntRDD = sc.parallelize(cnt.items(),3)
raw_mean = sum.join(raw_cntRDD).map(lambda (x, y): (x, tupleDivide(y)))

Would anyone provide some suggestion about the elegant coding style?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `aggregateByKey` for more optimal processing. The idea is that you store `state` vector which consists of count, min, max, and sum, and use aggregation functions to get the final values. Also, you can use tuple as a key, it is not necessary to concatenate keys into a single string.

```
data = [
        ['x', 'shop1', 1],
        ['x', 'shop1', 2],
        ['x', 'shop2', 3],
        ['x', 'shop2', 4],
        ['x', 'shop3', 5],
        ['y', 'shop4', 6],
        ['y', 'shop4', 7],
        ['y', 'shop4', 8]
    ]

def add(state, x):
    state[0] += 1
    state[1] = min(state[1], x)
    state[2] = max(state[2], x)
    state[3] += x
    return state

def merge(state1, state2):
    state1[0] += state2[0]
    state1[1] = min(state1[1], state2[1])
    state1[2] = max(state1[2], state2[2])
    state1[3] += state2[3]
    return state1

res = sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), x[2])).aggregateByKey([0, 10000, 0, 0], add, merge)

for x in res.collect():
    print 'Client "%s" shop "%s" : count %d min %f max %f avg %f' % (
        x[0][0], x[0][1],
        x[1][0], x[1][1], x[1][2], float(x[1][3])/float(x[1][0])
    )
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!