# Optimize Spark Numeric Functions (python)

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

New to Spark and looking to see the best way to optimize the below code. 
I have a file with 5GB file with 50 columns that I take about 30 columns out of it (in variable positions below). Then run various stats on it.

```
def numStats(position):
    results = []
    for lines in position:
        stats = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        myData = dataSplit.map(lambda arr: (arr[lines]))
        if myData.take(1) != [u'']:
            myData3 = myData.map(lambda line: line.split(',')).map(lambda fields: ("Column", float(fields[0]))).map(lambda (column, value) : (value)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
            stats[0] = myData3.sum()
            results.append(stats[0])
            stats[1] = myData3.min()
            results.append(stats[1])
            stats[2] = myData3.max()
            results.append(stats[2])
            stats[3] = myData3.mean()
            results.append(stats[3])
            stats[4] = myData3.stdev()
            results.append(stats[4])
            stats[5] = myData3.variance()
            results.append(stats[5])
            stats[6] = myData3.sampleStdev()
            results.append(stats[6])
            stats[7] = myData3.sampleVariance()
            results.append(stats[7])
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Is there anything you can see on how I might be able to optimize the code any further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can calculate many of the statistics within a single pass over the data with `aggregate` function (http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD). Here's an example of similar approach with `aggregateByKey` function: [How to optimize this code on spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287792/how-to-optimize-this-code-on-spark)
2. Each time you persist RDD for one column. Why don't you cache `myData` RDD instead? It is materialized each time you construct myData3 RDD, which means 30 times!

Finally, with `aggregate` function you would be able to calculate all the statistics within a single pass over your data